# How to fix pylint E1134: Non-mapping value X is used in a mapping context (not-a-mapping)

Tags: python, type-hinting, pylint, mypy, python-dataclasses

[pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) (2.12.2) is returning

> E1134: Non-mapping value self.f_four is used in a mapping context (not-a-mapping)

For the following code

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class One:
    f_one: str
    f_two: str

@dataclass
class Two:
    f_three: str
    f_four: One
    def __post_init__(self):
        """Initialise nested dataclass fields from a dictionary"""
        self.f_four = One(**self.f_four)

data = {'f_three': 'three', 'f_four': {'f_one': 'one', 'f_two': 'two'}}

print(Two(**data)) # prints: Two(f_three='three', f_four=One(f_one='one', f_two='two'))
```

With respect to dataclasses.field [the documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#:%7E:text=metadata%3A%20This%20can,in%20the%20metadata.):

> metadata: This can be a mapping or None. None is treated as an empty dict. This value is wrapped in MappingProxyType() to make it read-only, and exposed on the Field object. It is not used at all by Data Classes, and is provided as a third-party extension mechanism. Multiple third-parties can each have their own key, to use as a namespace in the metadata.

I tried updating the `Two` class with `f_four: One = field(metadata="Mapping")` instead. But this causes mypy errors (but resolved the pylint errors) therefore, this `metadata` must be incorrect or at least insufficient to fix this properly.
Mypy errors for the line that changed was

```
error: No overload variant of "field" matches argument type "str"
note: Possible overload variants:
note:     def [_T] field(*, default: _T, init: bool = ..., repr: bool = ..., hash: Optional[bool] = ..., compare: bool = ..., metadata: Optional[Mapping[Any, Any]] = ...) -> _T
note:     def [_T] field(*, default_factory: Callable[[], _T], init: bool = ..., repr: bool = ..., hash: Optional[bool] = ..., compare: bool = ..., metadata: Optional[Mapping[Any, Any]] = ...) -> _T
note:     def field(*, init: bool = ..., repr: bool = ..., hash: Optional[bool] = ..., compare: bool = ..., metadata: Optional[Mapping[Any, Any]] = ...) -> Any
```

So how do you properly resolve this pylint error?

Comment: What is the real version of pylint that you're using ? 2.9.12 does not exists. https://pypi.org/project/pylint/#history

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas Apologies 2.12.2

Comment: I had downvoted, but i was a bit annoyed. If you able to edit the post I can remove it.

Comment: @Mark its a bit hard for me to do because literally all I do is downvote posts, but will definitely try to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code I see two errors, one from pylint and one from mypy:

### pylint error

```py
self.f_four = One(**self.f_four)
# Non-mapping value self.f_four is used in a mapping context
```

pylint error happens because the [specially generated `__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) of the dataclass:

```py
def __init__(f_three: str, f_four: One)
```

`f_four` is a class `One` instance which does not accept `**`.

A solution for pylint is to manually define the signature of `__init__`,
and moving the body of `__post_init__` into `__init__`:

```py
from typing import Union
@dataclass
class Two:
    f_three: str
    f_four: One

    # __init__ f_four accepts both One and dict
    def __init__(self, f_three: str, f_four: Union[One, dict]):
        self.f_three = f_three
        if isinstance(f_four, dict):
            self.f_four = One(**f_four)
        else:
            self.f_four = f_four
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep `__post_init__` then permit `Two.f_four` to be: `Union[One, dict]`:

```py
from typing import Union
@dataclass
class Two:
    f_three: str
    f_four: Union[One, dict]

    def __post_init__(self):
        "Initialise nested dataclass fields from a dictionary"
        if isinstance(self.f_four, dict):
            self.f_four = One(**self.f_four)
```

### mypy error

```py
print(Two(**data))
# Argument 1 to "Two" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, Collection[str]]";
#     expected "str"
# Argument 1 to "Two" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, Collection[str]]";
#     expected "One"
```

There is a mypy error because `**data` does not match the type hints in
`Two.__init__`. To fix the mypy error we need a [`TypedDict`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#typeddict):

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class TwoDict(TypedDict):
    f_three: str
    f_four: Union[One, dict]
```

and we must say to mypy type hint that `data` has type `TwoDict`:

```py
data: TwoDict = {'f_three': 'three', 'f_four': {'f_one': 'one', 'f_two': 'two'}}
```

Comment: `f_four: One | dict` is equivalent to `f_four: Union[One, dict]`.